# Is Quantum teleportation possible for large objects like a cat, for example?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, time-travel, quantum-teleportation

Ok, here's the idea. This isn't really connected to what is usually referred to as 'quantum teleportation', but assuming that all particles can tunnel to a different location given the right circumstances, shouldn't it be possible that entities made of particles may also be able to do the same thing.

This is partly inspired by the deja vu scene in the Matrix, where Neo sees the cat appear at the doorway twice; I was thinking that the cat could have 'tunnelled' back to its original position in this way.

I know that, if there's any probability of this occurring at all it'd be minute, and I'd also like to know what - if any - role the exclusion principle plays in this. Would the particles need to be of the same energy, or would that not matter? Also, what would need to be the coherence/decoherence of the 'system' tunnelling to a new location.

I'd also be interested in trying to tease out any connections with relativity. The idea being that while tunnelling may be possible, in a wormhole-like fashion, because of it's mass-energy (that of a cat), it'd only be able to tunnel a short distance (more than likely), a few feet say.

Comment: If this question is inspired by Matrix, then the answer is right there: it's a bug in the simulation software; no quantum mechanics is needed. Now if you think there is any probability that all particles composing a cat can spontaneously move at the same time one meter to the right, don't you think that it is vastly more probable (*infinitely* more probable) that only some of them would do so, and also at different times, and not all exactly one meter to the right, making the average way a cat spontaneously leaks around by tunneling look pretty ugly? Fortunately this is not observed.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough, I was more just trying to see if there was some link, or links, between tunnelling entanglement and the idea of wormholes; it seems like there should be, that's all.

Comment: Google "ER=EPR" for links between wormholes and entanglement.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum teleportation does not move a particle between two locations.  It actually doesn't *move* anything between two locations.  It shifts the *entanglement* between, e.g., particles A and B to particles A and C. At best,quantum teleportation might be used to shift the "aliveness/deadness" of cat A and cat B (entangled if the aliveness/deadness of the two cats is quantum mechanically correlated) to aliveness/deadness of cat A and cat C.

Comment: Yes, I know, I did cover this in the question. My question was more about the probabilities involved with the tunnelling of large objects (like a cat) and attempting to conceptually bridge concepts in general relativity and quantum mechanics (i.e. tunnelling and Einstein-Rosen bridges).